# How do I edit complex Json data with Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I have a json production as below. Inside this json object, there is a json array with a unit name. There is more than one object in this array, but the number is not fixed. The keys and values ​​of the first Json object in the Json Array named unit are known. These values ​​are contained in first_keys = [] and first_values ​​= [].

What I want to do now is: For example, to calculate the "carb" value of the 2nd json object, the amount value in the 2nd json object will be multiplied by the "carb" value in the 1st json object and then divided by the amount value in the 1st json object. To give another example; 3. To calculate the "protein" value inside the json object, multiply the "amount" variable in the 3rd json object with the protein value in the 1st json object and then divide it by the "amount" variable inside the 1st json object.

```
{
    "food_id": 0,
    "food_name": "NAME",
    "food_image": "IMAGE",
    "food_kcal": "KCAL",
    "food_url": "FOOD_URL",
    "food_description": "DESC",
    "meal_time": "null",
    "food_category": "",
    "food_first_unit": "Yemek Kaşığı",
    "carb_percent": "72",
    "protein_percent": "23",
    "fat_percent": "4",
    "units": [
        {
            "unit": "100 Gram",
            "amount": "100",
            "kcal": "505 kcal",
            "carb": "65 g",
            "fiber": "3 g",
            "protein": "5 g",
            "fat": "24 g",
            "saturated_fat": "10 g",
            "salt": "0.7 g",
            "sugar": "34 g"
        },
        {
            "unit": "1 Adet",
            "amount": "5",
            "kcal": "",
            "carb": "",
            "fiber": "",
            "protein": "",
            "fat": "",
            "saturated_fat": "",
            "salt": "",
            "sugar": ""
        },
        {
            "unit": "1 Porsiyon",
            "amount": "30",
            "kcal": "",
            "carb": "",
            "fiber": "",
            "protein": "",
            "fat": "",
            "saturated_fat": "",
            "salt": "",
            "sugar": ""
        },
        {
            "unit": "1 Paket",
            "amount": "90",
            "kcal": "",
            "carb": "",
            "fiber": "",
            "protein": "",
            "fat": "",
            "saturated_fat": "",
            "salt": "",
            "sugar": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

MyCode:

```
url = 'www.example.com'
response = requests.get(url)
response.encoding = 'utf-8'
html = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('li')

units = []
first_key = []
first_values = []
names = []
grams = []

for item in items:
    name = item.get('data-ntr-srvname-param')
    if(str(name) not in "None"):
        names.append(str(name).replace("Gramda", "Gram"))


items = soup.find_all("li", {"data-ntr-gram-param": True})
for item in items:
    grams.append(float(item["data-ntr-gram-param"]))


for row in soup.select('table[data-ntr-target="facts"] tr'):
    name = row.select_one('td:nth-of-type(1)')
    value = row.select_one('td:nth-of-type(2)')

    if name is not None and value is not None:
        first_key.append(name.text.strip())
        first_values.append(value.text.strip())


for index, gram in enumerate(grams):
    replacedGram=str(gram).replace(".0", "")
    units.append({
        "unit": f"{names[index]}",
        "amount": f"{replacedGram}"
    })



data_dict = dict(zip(first_key, first_values))
for index, gram in enumerate(grams):
    units[index].update(data_dict)

json_obj = {
    "food_id": 0,
    "food_name": "NAME",
    "food_image": "IMAGE",
    "food_kcal": "KCAL",
    "food_url": "FOOD_URL",
    "food_description": "DESC",
    "meal_time": "null",
    "food_category":"",
    "food_first_unit": "FIRST",
    "carb_percent": "72",
    "protein_percent": "23",
    "fat_percent": "4",
    "units": units
}

print("***************")

print(json.dumps(json_obj, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))

print("***************")
```

Comment: Just turn the JSON into normal Python data using `json.loads`, manipulate it as much as you want, then pack it back up as JSON using `json.dumps` once you've made your changes? The JSON steps are basically boilerplate, are you asking how to perform the operations you're talking about, instead? Because the JSON aspect does not factor into that part, that's a pure python question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to this we need to keep track of the reference amounts and split the value from the unit in the reference unit.

Change the `json_obj` to `data` and the following code will obtain the results.

```
import pprint

reference = data["units"][0]
results = [reference]

for each in data["units"][1:]:
    results.append(
        dict(unit=each['unit'], amount=each['amount'], **{
            key: f"{float(each['amount']) / float(reference['amount']) * float(reference[key].split(' ')[0]):.2f} {reference[key].split(' ')[-1]}"
            for key, val in each.items()
            if key not in ["unit", "amount"]
        })
    )

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

output:

```json
{'unit': '100 Gram', 'amount': '100', 'kcal': '505 kcal', 'carb': '65 g', 'fiber': '3 g', 'protein': '5 g', 'fat': '24 g', 'saturated_fat': '10 g', 'salt': '0.7 g', 'sugar': '34 g'}
{'unit': '1 Adet', 'amount': '5', 'kcal': '25.25 kcal', 'carb': '3.25 g', 'fiber': '0.15 g', 'protein': '0.25 g', 'fat': '1.20 g', 'saturated_fat': '0.50 g', 'salt': '0.03 g', 'sugar': '1.70 g'}
{'unit': '1 Porsiyon', 'amount': '30', 'kcal': '151.50 kcal', 'carb': '19.50 g', 'fiber': '0.90 g', 'protein': '1.50 g', 'fat': '7.20 g', 'saturated_fat': '3.00 g', 'salt': '0.21 g', 'sugar': '10.20 g'}
{'unit': '1 Paket', 'amount': '90', 'kcal': '454.50 kcal', 'carb': '58.50 g', 'fiber': '2.70 g', 'protein': '4.50 g', 'fat': '21.60 g', 'saturated_fat': '9.00 g', 'salt': '0.63 g', 'sugar': '30.60 g'}
```

We split the reference json from the other data by using `data["units"][0]` and `data["units"][1:]`. This only works if there is atleast 1 `units` object.

Then in order to multiply the correct amounts we convert them to `floats` and use the f-string method of `.2f` to round the values on two decimals (making it a string again). If we do not use rounding here we will run into the floating point precision error.